# html tag not shown properly in php

Tags: php, html, tags

```
$myfile = mysql_query($query_myfile, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_myfile = mysql_num_rows($myfile);
$typ_d = '';
$test='';


while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($myfile) ) 
{
   if ( $typ_d != $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ] ) 
   {

       $typ_d = $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ];

       echo "<h2>$typ_d</h2>";

   }
   if ( $test != $row_myfile[ 'test' ] ) 
   {

       $test = $row_myfile[ 'test' ];

       echo "<h3>$test</h3>";
   }

   echo "<li><a href=\"myfileDetail.php?myfile_id=".$row_myfile['myfile_id']. "\">";
   echo $row_myfile['shortname'].' ';
   echo $row_myfile['name']; ?></a></li>

   <?php } ?>
```

This code list out element in group and subgroups like this

Typ_d (group) generated by

```
echo "<h2>$typ_d</h2>";
```

test(subgroup) generated by

```
echo "<h3>$test</h3>";
```

then the lists  generated by

```
echo "<li><a href=\"myfileDetail.php?myfile_id=".$row_myfile['myfile_id']. "\">";
       echo $row_myfile['shortname'].' ';
       echo $row_myfile['name']; ?></a></li>
```

I have a problem generation the html tag as follow

```
<h2>Typ_d1</h2>
<h3> Test1</h3>
<ul>
  <li> List1</li>
  <li> List2 </li>
  <li>List3 </li>
</ul>
<h2>Typ_d2 </h2>
<h3>Test2</h3>
<ul>
  <li> List1</li>
  <li> List2</li>
  <li> List3</li>
</ul>
<h2> Typ_d3</h2>
<h3> Test3</h3>
<ul>
  <li> List1</li>
  <li> List2 </li>
  <li>List3 </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried so much but i cannot get it with the right order ..need help please

the current out put has not <`ul`> tag and I would like to put it in side the code

this is the current output

```
<li> List1</li>
  <li> List2 </li>
  <li>List3 </li>

<h2>Typ_d2 </h2>
<h3>Test2</h3>

  <li> List1</li>
  <li> List2</li>
  <li> List3</li>

<h2> Typ_d3</h2>
<h3> Test3</h3>

  <li> List1</li>
  <li> List2 </li>
  <li>List3 </li>
```

Comment: Can you show us what your current output looks like.

Comment: i think you only missing <ul> tag.

Comment: yea but how can i put <ul> tag so that it have the above html form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, without doing a major restructuring of your code (e.g. into an MVC pattern), you're better off compiling the data into an array first and then looping over that to generate the output, like @Blowski said.  Something like this:

```
$myfile = mysql_query($query_myfile, $db) or die(mysql_error());


$groups = array();

while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc( $myfile ) ) {

  $typ_d = $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ];

  $groups[ $typ_d ][ 'h2' ] = $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ];

  $groups[ $typ_d ][ 'h3' ] = $row_myfile[ 'test' ];

  $groups[ $typ_d ][ 'files' ][] = <<<DOCHERE
<li>
<a href="myfileDetail.php?myfile_id="{$row_myfile[ 'myfile_id' ]}">{$row_myfile[ 'shortname' ]} {$row_myfile[ 'name' ]}</a>
</li>
DOCHERE;

}
// while


foreach ( $groups as &$group ) {

  $group[ 'files' ] = join( "\n\n", $group[ 'files' ] );

  $group = <<<DOCHERE
<h2>
{$group[ 'h2' ]}
</h2>

<h3>
{$group[ 'h3' ]}
</h3>

<ul>

{$group[ 'files' ]}

</ul>
DOCHERE;

}
// foreach


echo join( "\n\n\n", $groups );
```

Notes:

- You should almost certainly be html-escaping the variable values before outputting them in HTML.
- I've eliminated the ugly concatenation for HTML output generation and replaced it with variable interpolation.
- I've eliminated the ill-advised double-quoting of HTML output strings and used `HEREDOC`s instead.
- There are a lot of variations on details of how you could do this, e.g. call `array_key_exists()` in the while loop instead of just re-assigning the `h2` and `h3` keys each time, assign `$groups[ $typ_d ]` by reference to shorten the other assignment statements, etc.

Comment: JMM Thank you very much for ur great effort !why is the while and foreach are commented out // and below the second while am getting a lot of syntax error

Comment: Thanks @Mark.  "why is the while and foreach are commented out //" -- you mean the "// while" and "// foreach" comments following the closing braces?  That's just a convention I use to mark the ends of blocks so it's easier to recognize what the closing brace is for.  "below the second while am getting a lot of syntax error" -- what are you getting errors from, the foreach loop?  Can you post them?  Make sure you have no spaces / tabs / any character but newline following the "DOCHERE;" parts.  What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: $group['files'] = join( "\n\n", $group['files']);  just says syntax error

Comment: Unfortunately that's not much to go on, and I don't see what about that line would cause an error. Standard PHP error reporting would say something more than just "syntax error", so I don't know what's going on there. Is any output generated?

Comment: That second message "{$group['h2']} syntax error unexpected '}'" suggests there's something wrong with the start of the `HEREDOC`: <<<DOCHERE. I think you might need to take this over to sitepoint forums or somewhere like that to debug further.

Answer (score 1):

As @jit pointed out, you're not echoing the `<ul>` tag anywhere. The structure of your code makes this a little difficult.

Restructure your code along the MVC design pattern:

1. A model runs the database query and assigns the results to an array.
2. A controller gets the results of that query and passes them to a view.
3. A view has nicely formatted HTML with only simple PHP statements.

The view would do something like (obviously, you need to format to your needs):

```
<?php if($type1 == $row->getType() ?><h2><?php echo $type1 ?></h2><?php endif ?>
<h3><?php echo $type2 ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php foreach($results as $row) : ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $row->getLink() ?>"><?php echo $row->getText() ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Some of the benefits of this approach are that your database query is more reusable, and the output HTML is much easier to read and edit.

Comment: thanx! but for now with out restructuring my code, is there a short cut to do this

Comment: You need to get the `<ul>` after the `<h3>`, so somehow you need to work out when it's echoing the first row as opposed to all the others that come after it. In my experience, you'll spend longer trying to get that to work than doing a bit of refactoring - plus your code will be a lot more maintainable in the future.

Comment: I dont have so much knowledge in php and also MVC design pattern. I dont really know what i have to change. I tried to put <ul> after <h3> but as you said it took me long and still couldn't get it right

Comment: The problem in your current code is that you would need to check on each row whether it should open a new `<ul>` - that's complicated and inefficient. Instead, you can do 'MVC light' by making two separate sections of your PHP file. The first should make an array of arrays - each array should contain the relevant rows for that group of `<li>`s. Then you can use a `foreach` to loop through the first level of arrays - insert the `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<ul>` tags. Then use a nested `foreach` to insert the `<li>`s, and then close the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br/>` at end of each echo statement.

Comment: I would rather to have <ul> tag for the unsorted list